# Не работает телеграм бот в групповых чатах

Tags: python, telebot

Не могу понять почему телеграм бот не работает в чатах где есть больше одного человека.
Бота я писал на языке Python с использованием библиотеки TelegramBotAPI. Я уже через ботфазе настраивал так как мне говорили, но ничего так и не происходило.

Вот мой код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from telebot.types import Message

bot = telebot.TeleBot('1992588049:AAGYnKGqlkW4pfSC7Z7eCnT0xAJoxY_9kzc');


@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):


    if message.text == "/help":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "А на этом канале список комманд вот такой: \n /help \n /info \n /money")
    elif message.text == "/info":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет дорогой друг! \n Ты сейчас находишься на начинающем телеграм канале по рисовке и обработке фотографий. Здесь ты сможешь заказать арт как другу или хорошую аватарку для соц-сетей. Главным художником и пока основыными выступает следующий аккаунт: \n @Kirill_Bondarev12 \n")

    elif message.text == "/money":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Любой каприз за ваши деньги.\nСоздания арта: от 249 рублей\nОбработка фотографий: от 299 рублей\nШапка для YouTube канала: от 199 рублей\nСделать свой пост в нашем канале: от 49 рублей")
    
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я твоя не понимать")


    
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Под настройкой ботфазер вы имели ввиду, что включили Allow Groups?

Comment: Так же советую переписать бота, что бы он работал не через ифы, а через спецыальный handler.(Выглядит он так : @bot.message_handler(commands=['start']))

Пример использования из реального проекта :
@bot.message_handler(commands=['menu'])
def command_menu(message):
    try:
        if input_delete.get(message.chat.id) == None:
            open_menu(message)
    except:
        open_menu(message)